# Keep changed app icon after app update?

Tags: macos, mac, icon

I had used [CandyBar](http://www.panic.com/blog/2012/08/candybar-mountain-lion-and-beyond/) to change my Mail.app icon. After apply the 10.8.2 Supplemental Update 1, the Mail.app icon has reverted. How can I prevent that from happening in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you update your OS - (if it contains a Mail.app update) it will replace the previous version of the app with the new one and by doing this it will also replace the icon file.

Anyway something that you can try after you've replaced the icon again:

1.Open Terminal and enter this command - `sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.p/Contents/MacOS/Finder`

2.Enter your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

3.WITHOUT switching to other windows press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> and select Finder

4.Press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> this will open a new Finder Window with root privileges (BE EXTREMELY CAREFUL WHAT YOU DO)

5.Press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and enter `/Applications/Mail.app/Contents/Resources`

6.Find the `Mail.icns`(it should be the new one you chose) file - Right Click it and select `Get Info`

7.Check the `Locked` attribute.

8.Go back to the terminal window and press <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> this will close the Finder Window.

This should prevent it from being overwritten

---

Command line alternative:

`sudo chflags uchg /pathToFile/filename`

Comment: Is there any way to do that all via the shell?

Comment: Oh yes, of course. You would simply do this:
`sudo chflags uchg /pathToFile/filename`